# Ways to make table top removable from base/legs

Tags: woodworking, furniture, table

I just finished my first wood project and it's a farmhouse table. I am going to be bringing this to college and I need a way to make the top removable from the base so it wont be so challenging to transport. I don't think anything involving screws will be a great idea because eventually the screw holes will get warped. What are some of your ideas to make this baby detachable??

[image: the top is just resting on the base in this photo]

Comment: How is it attached now? Without the top I would worry about the leg assembly twisting and damaging itself unless that also breaks down.

Comment: it is just resting on the legs as of now. not attached.

Comment: Well you built it, other than screws ,,, What about a chain saw and some Gorilla glue to re assemble ,,, ok probably not helpful. How is it built?

Comment: Taking the top off will not make the base significantly smaller or more transportable unless you want to disassemble the base. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @bib make it easier to move. Not as heavy/awkward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this kind of fitting:

[image]

Each block is permanently screwed to either the top or the base. You connect the parts using a supplied machine screw (not a wood screw).

Comment: +1 Basically machined cleats. The same could be done with wooden cleats and nuts bolt and washers, but these are elegant.